# file provider between 2 app with same signature

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-fileprovider

Someone could help me to understand what wrong with that.

I have 2 app ( Server and Client ). I own these 2 app and they have the same signature. The client need to read some file from the server and I want to do it with FileProvider.

//SERVER SIDE

```
<permission
    android:name="${package_name_lite}.permission.FILE_PROVIDER.READ"
    android:description="@string/fp_permission_description"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_forward_24dp"
    android:label="File provider permission"
    android:permissionGroup="Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<provider
        android:name="provider.fileProvider.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${package_name_lite}.file.provider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:permission="${package_name_lite}.permission.FILE_PROVIDER.READ">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

//CLIENT SIDE

```
<uses-permission android:name="${package_name_lite}.permission.FILE_PROVIDER.READ"/>
```

My client know the uri path, I don't want to ask them with any intent. Whatever my server is able to supply, my client has a way to perfectly know the uri path. Si I build them like this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + myPath);
```

My issue start here, if I tried to use this uri which is perfectly good, i have a security issue.

1- How can my client get the permission for my uri obtained form parse string ?

2- android:grantUriPermissions="false" -> I don't want to grant permissions to everyone, I want this FileProvider work only between my 2 app. But if I put this to false, the app won't compile

So to sum up : How to use FileProvider between 2 owned app with same signature protected from any unwanted access with permission signature and without the need to request the Uri with intent ?

Thanks, any help would be appreciated

Comment: When using FileProvider the server has to grand the permission to the client. This is done on the used intent.

Comment: If you want it the way you described you should extend ContentProvider class. And having the same signature is not needed. Other apps can use it too.

Comment: The problem with content provider, you can not share Uri. I need my client to have Uri to be able to open an Input stream from my server file. So how can I have a input stream from my client without the need to ask a path because I already know it... Thanks :)

Comment: `you can not share Uri.` Sorry, i dont know what you mean. If the app can build up the right uri then it can open a stream for that uri. You do that now too. Just use a different authority.

Comment: I need to read file in another app I own. I don't want my open app to read all file the send the bytes. So I need app A to open an input stream of appB file. Without doing all boiler plate intent stuff because I already know the path of the files I need.

Comment: Service and Aidl, I didn't find anything about input or output stream. Content provider is for data or you need to read the whole file and send it as bytes. File provider the permission make the stuff useless. So android have no option to let owner app to share file between them without overwork or over code ?

Comment: Yes your server (please dont suddenly start with appA and B,  in another app, my open app, very confusing) does not have to use an intent. Your client can build up the right uri and then open an InputStream for that uri and read the bytes of the file. Implementing your own ContentProvider is not that much work. Only a few methods have to be overwritten with not much code.

Comment: Seem content provider can do it through the overriding method about FileDescriptor. Gonna give a try to this way, hope there no over permission management. And a single permission signature will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

So at the end, it was very easy to do. If you need to open an input stream file from one app to another one you own (both). Don't bother with FileProvider. You just need to use ContentProvider stuff.

Just set up your manifest with the permission custom permission you need to protect your stuff

Then in ContentProvider, you need to just override 1 method.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String link = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    File file = File.from(link);
    if(!file.exists()){
        throw new FileNotFoundException("no file found for " + link);
    }
    else {
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file.getFile(), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    }
}
```

And then side the app you need to open a stream:

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
        .authority(AUTHORITY)
        .scheme(SCHEME_CONTENT)
        .appendEncodedPath(file.toLinkString())
        .build();
resolver.openInputStream(uri );
```

ps: file.toLinkString() and File.fromLink(...) are personal method which transform the path in something like this "@:PRIVATE_DATA_FILE:#:test:png" You can use the normal path or use whatever you want. Doesn't need to comply to anything since that the AUTHORITY which make you able to reach your server app.

Comment: thanks to  @blackapps  who make me realize you could open a stream with ContentProvider :)

Comment: Thanks, does it work this way without exporting the provider? (with same signatures)